# pointwise convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that the sequence $f_n = nx^n$ converges pointwise on [0,1) ?

I was trying to do this by definition, we have that if $nx^n < \epsilon$ then $log(n) + nlog(x) < log(\epsilon) \Leftrightarrow nlog(x) log(\epsilon) - log(n) < log(\epsilon)$ then we get $n >\frac{log(\epsilon)}{log (x)}$ .

So I found a $n$ that should work in the definition of pointwise convergence, but I could not write te proof properly. Anyone with a better idea?

Comment: The first thing is intuition. What does $n(1/2)^n = n/2^n$ do?

Answer (score 2):

For $x=0$, $f_n(x)=0$ so convergence is trivial.

Let $x\in (0,1)$, then 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty} n \exp(n \log(x))$$

$$   \phantom{textexttexttext s} = \lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{1}{\log(1/x)} m \exp(-m) ,$$

$$   \phantom{textexttexttext s} =\frac{1}{\log(1/x)}  \lim_{m\to \infty} m \exp(-m) ,$$

$$=0\phantom{texttextt}$$

where we have defined $m=n \log(1/x)$ and it was used that $\lim_{n\to\infty} m \exp(-m)=0$, which follows from l'Hôpital's rule.

Hope this is more helpful.

Comment: but to get the inequalities I forced $nx^n$ to be less than ϵ, and I think when I am writing the proof I have to go from the $\vert f_n(x) - 0\vert$ and get that this is less than $\epsilon$... I hope you get what I am trying to say. Thanks !

Comment: I made an edit, please let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that for a fixed $x \in [0,1)$, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} nx^n =0$.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} nx^n &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{x^{-n}} \\ \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{-n} \ln x} \tag{l'hospital} \\ \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{\ln x} \\ \\
&= \frac 1{\ln x} \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = \frac 1{\ln x}  \ \cdot \ 0 = 0
\end{align*}